# Invisible Insta-Boom Creepers

Tags: minecraft-commands

So I was making a trench warfare map and i needed grenades. So first i turned MobGreifing to false. Now, It works by taking the impact of a snowball (using armor stands to detect) and summoning a creeper with the following attributes:
-Invisibility
-Instant Fuse
-Kinda Large Explosion Radius (about 3?)

I just need a /summon command. Thanks.

P.S. MobGreifing is false, so it's basically an entity killer.

Comment: What have you tried to accomplish this yourself? This community helps better if we knew what you tried, so that we know what you haven't done that would work.

Comment: Flagging question as unclear because it does not specify which edition is being played.

Answer (score 2):

This command is probably about what you are looking for:

```
summon Creeper ~ ~ ~ {Fuse:0,ExplosionRadius:3,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Duration:1000,Ambience:0}]}
```

The *ActiveEffects* is for invisibilty but with a fuse of 0, you will see the creeper right before it explodes before the effect is applied.

If you want a simpler command, I would omit it:

```
summon Creeper ~ ~ ~ {Fuse:0,ExplosionRadius:3}
```

For more information on the subject, [here is the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Creeper#Data_values) on creeper data values.